# In Angular JS - how to use ng-include to make my code generic and reusable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

Using the AngularJS, 
I want to use ng-include to make my code generic.

So here is my problem:

I want to have my 'ang-attribute.html' file used in the ng-include to be as generic as possible, and for that I want to get the attribute name outside of the html.

With something like this:

```
<div data-field-name="display_name">
    <div ng-include="'ang-attribute.html'"></div>
</div>
```

In my html file I would like to use the data-field-name, and then use it again with a different value.

I tried to get it via DOM... and couldn't find a way to do that.

So in my ng-include html file I have the following line:

```
<div ng-controller="attributeCtrl">
    <div class="my-profile-constant-text">{{displayAttribute}}:</div>
....
</div>
```

Maybe there is a way to pass a constructor to the controller and then I could pass my data-field-name into it?
Or any other solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want to be looking at directives, this has an attributes object easily accessible after the dom has rendered to re-use.
Html

```
<my-directive field-name="display_name"></my-directive>
```

Directive

```
angular
.module("myApp", [])
.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<div>{{exposeAttribute}}</div>",
        //templateUrl: "mytemplate.html",
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.exposeAttribute = attr.fieldName;
        }
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mhCaD/

Comment: Hi, this was very helpful... but I still have a problem using this directive as you can see in here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mhCaD/2/

I want to send different fields but I get only one result...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: by adding the:    scope: 'isolate', to the directive I got the result I wanted!